# Database indexes for URLs

Tags: database, indexing, nosql

I have to store millions of URLs in a database, and be able to find rows by URL quickly.

**MySQL**'s string indexes aren't quick enough for this, because they only index the first 4 characters of the string, which are generally `www.`, and then MySQL iterates over each of those rows starting with `www.` and compares the value with the URL I searched for.

**MongoDB** doesn't let you customize how many characters are indexed for strings, and [the docs aren't very detailed](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes), so I don't think MongoDB is suitable.

**Google App Engine** has a special URL type, which is great, but I can't use GAE.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> MySQL's string indexes aren't quick enough for this, because they only index the first 4 characters of the string, which are generally www., and then MySQL iterates over each of those rows starting with www. and compares the value with the URL I searched for.

This is not true. `MySQL` can index up to `1000` bytes for `MyISAM` and `767` bytes for `InnoDB`.

If you only need literal matches for your `URL` strings, index their hashes.

This will keep your index size low (`16` byte per key if you use something like `MD5`) and the key values will be distributed evenly.

Answer (score 1):

If you use MySQL, read pages 103-104 of [High Performance MySQL (2nd ed.)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101716) (link allows you to search inside book - look for "pseudohash"), which covers hashing approach for indexing URLs. Most importantly, it suggests using MySQL's CRC32 function instead of MD5 for better performance because it produces a shorter value that can be compared more rapidly.